# How to refrain a file from being committed while keeping the ability to have it being overwritten when pulling from others?

Tags: git, gitignore

Me and my friends are working in the same project.

There is a file that I want to change locally, but I don't want other to receive my changes. However, if they modify it, then I want to receive their changes. If I have already had changed it, then I want it to be overwritten automatically.

Is the solution is that I put that file to the gitignore and they don't?

Should I push the gitignore file?

I want to make sure I have the solution before proposing, but I don't know how to test it alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During your own development you should:

1. Don't add it to `.gitignore`.
2. Edit it as you want.
3. `git add` changed files but (not) the `<kept file>`.
4. Commit and push.

When you have to pull:

1. `git stash save`
2. `git pull`
3. `git stash pop` (to recover/merge your `<kept file>` local changes)

Comment: *4*. (in the second part) Resolve conflicts. ;-)

Comment: Yes, it may be required by the situation.

Comment: If the user is prepared to resolve conflicts all 4 points can be condensed to [`git pull --autostash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---autostash).

Comment: Well, this is a good alternative.

Comment: if I already ignore a file, is it correct that it will be noticed in `git status`?